# Get the latest timestamp from MySQL

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a query that requires to get the latest timestamp. Below are my tables. Thanks in advance.

Table 1: CmInfo

| MacAddress | NodeID |
| --- | --- |
| 1234567890 | 1234 |

Table 2: ResetDetails

| MacAddress | ResetReason |
| --- | --- |
| 1234567890 | Reboot |

Tabl3 3: CmCollection

| timestamp | NodeID |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-20 11:00 | 1234 |
| 2022-03-20 11:10 | 1234 |
| 2022-03-20 11:15 | 1234 |

Required output: Just get the latest timestamp from table3 and join with table1 and 2.

| Timestamp | MacAddress | ResetReason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-20 11:15 | 1234567890 | Reboot |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following query

```
SELECT timestamp,
       CI.macaddress,
       resetreason
FROM   (SELECT nodeid,
               Max(timestamp) timestamp
        FROM   cmcollection
        GROUP  BY nodeid) CC
       JOIN cminfo CI
         ON CC.nodeid = CI.nodeid
       JOIN resetdetails RD
         ON RD.macaddress = CI.macaddress
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try a query like this:

```
SELECT c.MacAddress, MAX(cc.timestamp) , r.MacAddress
FROM CmInfo c
LEFT JOIN ResetDetails r ON r.MacAddress = c.MacAddress
LEFT JOIN CmCollection cc ON cc.NodeID = c.NodeID
WHERE c.MacAddress = "1234567890";
```

Comment: thanks mate. but I'm getting Unknown column 'CmInfo.mac' in where clause.

Comment: @Alex Tulio - i hav correct it - sorry